# Multiple glPrimitiveRestartIndex calls

Tags: opengl

I've loaded to my vertex array multiple polygons which I want to draw with GL_TRIANGLE_FAN.
I'm trying to performe this using a single call to glDrawArrays and also using glPrimitiveRestartIndex, to specify where a new polygon starts.
Can I call glPrimitiveRestartIndex multiple times? For example, if I have loaded 3 polygons of 8 vertex each (24 vertex in total). Can I do something like this:

```
glPrimitiveRestartIndex(8);
glPrimitiveRestartIndex(16);
```

And then call glDrawArrays?
It seems not to work. It seems OpenGL just take into account the last call to glPrimitiveRestartIndex.

Answer (score 5):

There is only one primitive restart index. The [`glPrimitiveRestartIndex`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glPrimitiveRestartIndex) function sets that one restart index.

Think about it: how would you turn an index *off* (so that it is no longer a restart index) if there were more than one?

Do not use `glDrawArrays` with primitive restarting.

Comment: Well, actually I didn't understand. What is glPrimitiveRestartIndex for?
I thought it was used to combine several glDrawArrays (or glDrawElements) in a single call. Isn't it?

Comment: @Guto: The restart index is the index that, when fetched from the index buffer (hint hint) doesn't actually specify a vertex. It instead means that the primitive should be restarted. So if you set the restart index to 65535, and draw {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 65535, 5, 6, 7, 8} as a `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP`, you will get 5 triangles. The first three from the first 5 indices, and the next two from the last 4. 65535 is what says to restart.

Comment: First, it is primitive restart **index**, so it affects only indexed mode i.e. `glDrawElements`, while `glDrawArrays` is unaffected. Second, it is used to specify index value that means end of primitive (restarting a primitive).